# Using session to transfer table values

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, html-table

Im trying to build a website for vehicle renting and i have managed to display the vehicles in a table but now i want to add a booking button for each vehicle and display booking form on a different page.im trying to do this using sessions is that possible?

display page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basicstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php
    include("header.php"); 
    $disp = "select * from selfdrive where City = '" . strtoupper($_SESSION['city']) . "' and Availability = 'YES' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $disp);
    echo $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<table id= "vehicle-display" width="1088" height="49" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="250" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="250" scope="col">Model</th>
    <th width="200" scope="col">Class</th>
    <th width="200" scope="col">Deposit</th>
    <th width="200" scope="col">Daily Rate</th>
  </tr>
  <?php

    $i=1;
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {       

    //$Image=mysql_result($result,$i,"Image");
    //$Model=mysql_result($result,$i,"Model");
    //$Class=mysql_result($result,$i,"Class");
    //$Deposit=mysql_result($result,$i,"Deposit");
    //$Rate=mysql_result($result,$i,"Rate");
    //echo "$Image $Model $Class $Deposit $Rate";
    //$i++;
    ?>
    <form action="self-booking.php" method="get">
  <tr>
    <th width="250" scope="col"><img src="<?php echo $row['Image']?>" width="200"></th>
    <th width="250" scope="col"><?php echo $row['Model']?></th>
    <th width="200" scope="col"><?php echo $row['Class']?></th>
    <th width="200" scope="col"><?php echo $row['Deposit']?></th>
    <th width="200" scope="col"><?php echo $row['Rate']?></th>
    <th width="200" scope="col"><input type="submit" value="Book Now!" name="submit">
    <?php for($i=0;$i < $num;$i++){$_SESSION['row']['$i'] = $row['$i'];}?></th>
  </tr>
  </form>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

booking form page

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include("session.php");
    include("header.php");
?>



<html>
<head>
<title>Booking</title>
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basicstyle.css">
</head>

<body class="templatemo-bg-gray">
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
        header("Location: login.php");
    else{   
?>
    <h1 class="margin-bottom-15">Login</h1>

    <?php $row = $_SESSION['row']['$i']; ?>
    <div id="imageframe">
        <img src="<?php echo $row['Image']?>" width="600">
    </div>
    <div id="vehicle-details">
    <?php   echo "Model: ".$row['Model']."<br><br>";
            echo "Class: ".$row['Class']."<br><br>";
            echo "Deposit: Rs.".$row['Deposit']."<br><br>";
            echo "Daily Rate: Rs.".$row['Rate']."<br><br>";
    ?>
    </div>



<?php } ?>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you need to store `$row`, you have to start session before you list them out. And you should treat your `$_SESSION['row']` to be an array. So when you run the while loop, you can `$_SESSION['row'][] = $row;` to store it. But in your code, I think you actually want to pass them to the other page, that's not gonna make it.

Comment: You can't call `session_start()` after *any* output it sent to the browser. Put it at the top of your script.

Comment: @AkiEru i tried saving it as $_SESSION['row']['$i'] = $row['$i'] with $i in a for loop. but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @RobbieAverill yea. thanks. fixed that one.

Comment: Should you check with the database at the start of loading a page as some cars might getting booking in the intervening period of time and therefore will not be available

Comment: i guess i should, but i dont actually have enough time left to do that. i gotta submit this tomorrow so im doing it like a beta version. i understand that most of my code isnt very efficient. but can't help that right now.

Answer (score 1):

ok so i figured it out. Apparently theres no need for sessions. i could just pass the values to a variable in the url and use get/post to read it in the next page.

```
  <tr>
<th width="250" scope="col"><img src="<?php echo $row['Image']?>" width="200"></th>
<th width="250" scope="col"><?php echo $row['Model']?></th>
<th width="200" scope="col"><?php echo $row['Class']?></th>
<th width="200" scope="col"><?php echo $row['Deposit']?></th>
<th width="200" scope="col"><?php echo $row['Rate']?></th>
<th width="200" scope="col"><?php echo "<a href=self-booking.php?vid=".$row['VehicleID'].">Book Now!</a>";?> </th>
```

and the reading...

```
<?php $vid = $_GET['vid']; 
//echo"<pre>";
//print_r($row);
//echo"</pre>";
$sql = "select * from selfdrive where VehicleID = '".$vid."';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$model = $row['Model'];
$class = $row['Class'];
$deposit = $row['Deposit'];
$rate = $row['Rate'];

$sql2 = "select * from customers where Username = '".$_SESSION['login_user']."';";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
?>
```